# page not displaying when using login but the code of page is displaying

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying put login credentials to access my web page: 
I wrote this in login.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Please type your Username and Password... </title>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript" src="login.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#eeeeee">
        <form>
            <br>
            <center>
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" style="background:#bfbfbf;color:#212121;border-color:#212121;" onFocus="this.style.background = '#ffffff';" onBlur="this.style.background = '#bfbfbf';">
            <br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password" style="background:#bfbfbf;color:#212121;border-color:#212121;" onFocus="this.style.background = '#ffffff';" onBlur="this.style.background = '#bfbfbf';">
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="Login" onClick="Login(this.form);" style="background:#bfbfbf;color:#000000;border-color:#212121;" onMouseOver="this.style.color = '#404040';" onMouseOut="this.style.color = '#000000';" onFocusr="this.style.color = '#404040';" onBlur="this.style.color = '#000000';">
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I wrote this JS in login.js

```
function Login(form) {
    username = new Array("u1","u2");
    password = new Array("p1","p2");
    page = "untitled_1" + ".php";
    if (form.username.value == username[0] && form.password.value == password[0] || form.username.value == username[1] && form.password.value == password[1])
    {
        self.location.href = page;
    } else {
        alert("Either the username or password you entered is incorrect.\nPlease try again.");
        form.username.focus();
    }
    return true;
}
```

So when I open the page I enter the credentials and then login. The browser displays the code of the page "untitled_1.php" all the php and html code but not the page :(

Help please!!

Comment: I sincerely hope you don't intend to use this login procedure in any real application.

Comment: `page = "untitled_1" + ".php";` ???

Comment: @alfasin untitled_1.php is the page it must redirect to after login

Comment: @JBNizet y?

Suggest something more better

Comment: JavaScript is executed at client-side, in the browser. Anyone can right-click in your login page, click "View page source", read the JavaScript code, find the user name and password sitting there, in clear, and enter those in the login form.

Comment: @JBNizet so then this really sucks....what is the best alternative to use authentication for my web site.

Comment: The alternative is to store the users and passwords (salted and hashed) in a database, at server side. Submit your login form to the server, have the server check them, and re-display the login form until the login and password are correct.

Comment: @JBNizet okay thankyou :) will do that

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a web server running PHP. `php` files are just text files and the browser will display them as such unless you have a server running. If you don't have any PHP code, rename it to `.html` and it should work!

If you do have PHP code, make sure the file is in your `www` directory (whatever you have it called, `public_html` maybe) so the web server can handle it and it is configured to execute `php` files. If you don't have a server, you can install something like [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Comment: I have wamp running but it doesn't show do you think this should be different?

self.location.href = page;

Comment: Your code isn't the problem. It's your server configuration. Are you accessing the page via `file://C:/...myfile.html` or `http://localhost/...`?

Comment: I right click on it and select run in chrome. 

All the web pages I opened the similar way and the php code got executed...but this way not working

Comment: So answer my question. Can you get to it by going to a `http://localhost...` url?

Comment: ya i can get directly via localhost but not using the login

Comment: How are you getting to the login page? Using a localhost url?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13385/discussion-between-sachleen-and-user1424394)

Answer (score 0):

You have not configured Apache correctly to execute `.php` files.

Comment: I ran many till now...still running too. But this doesn'tget displayed

Comment: Is there anything different about this PHP file then? Different extension? Content problems?